# Does Golang automatically assign variables as arguments when writing function closures?

Tags: function, go, closures

Here is the code I'm referring to:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func adder() func(int) int {
    sum := 0
    return func(x int) int {
        sum += x
        return sum
    }
}

func main() {
    pos, neg := adder(), adder()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(
            pos(i),
            neg(-2*i),
        )
    }
}
```

Following is the output when it is run:

```
    0 0
    1 -2
    3 -6
    6 -12
    10 -20
    15 -30
    21 -42
    28 -56
    36 -72
    45 -90
```

I don't get how `x` is being assigned in the `return` statement in the `adder` function? It does not seem to be passed anywhere in the function.
I also don't get how the `sum` variable works. Shouldn't it get reset everytime the function `adder` is called and be assigned the value `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go handles first-class functions and closures in a pretty typical / standard way.  For some good background on closures in general, see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).  In this case, calling `adder` itself:

1. Creates the `int` object named `sum` with value `0`.
2. Returns a closure: a function-like thingy<sup>1</sup> that, when called, has access to the variable `sum`.

The particular function-like thingy that `adder` returns, which its caller captures in an ordinary variable, is a function that takes one argument.  You then call it, passing the one argument.  There's nothing special about this argument-passing: it works the same way as it would anywhere else.  Inside the function-like thingy, using the variable `x` gets you the value that the caller passed.  Using the name `sum` gets you the captured `int` object, whatever its value is.  Returning from the function leaves the captured `int` still captured, so a later call to the same function-like thingy sees the updated `int` in `sum`.

By calling `adder` twice, you get two slightly-different function-like thingies: each one has its own private `sum`.  Both of these private `sum`s are initially zero.  Calling the function-like thingy whose value you've saved in `pos` gets you the function that uses one of them.  Calling the slightly-different function-like thingy whose value you've saved in `neg` gets you the function that uses the other one.

---

<sup>1</sup>There's no real difference between this "function-like thingy" and an actual function *except* that this particular function-like thingy doesn't have a *name* by which you can invoke it.  That's more or less what it means to have first-class functions.

---

#### If you're stuck on readability issues...

The original form of this is:

```
func adder() func(int) int {
    sum := 0
    return func(x int) int {
        sum += x
        return sum
    }
}
```

Let's rewrite this with a few type names and other syntactic changes that leave the core of the code the same.  First, let's make a name that means `func(int) int`:

```
type adderClosure func(int) int
```

Then we can use that to rewrite `adder`s first line:

```
func adder() adderClosure {
    ...
}
```

Now let's make a local variable inside adder to hold the function we're going to return.  To be explicit and redundant, we can use this type again:

```
    var ret adderClosure // not good style: just for illustration
```

Let's now assign that variable to our closure by doing this:

```
    sum := 0
    ret = func(x int) int {
        sum += x
        return sum
    }
```

and then we can `return ret` to return the closure.  [Here's the complete code on the Go Playground.](https://play.golang.org/p/hxLKKAktRD9)

Comment: Thanks! I still have a doubt with the syntax though. In the declaration of `adder`, the code is `func adder() func(int) int{...}`. What I don't get is how is the variable `x` being passed on to the closure?Shouldn't `x` be first passed on to `adder`, like `func adder(x int)` and then adder passes it to the closure? Or is it that since closure is declared with `func(int) int`, Golang automatically gets it that `x` which is an `int` has to be passed on to the closure? I'm from C++ background so this syntax confuses me.

Comment: Everything after the literal text `func adder()` before the open brace for the function itself is the *return type*. In this case, the return type is `func(int) int`. The name `x` only appears later, when we write the function that `adder` will wrap up into a closure-thingy and return.

Comment: So when we call `pos(i)`, Golang knows that the variable `i` has to be passed on to the _return type_ `func(int)`.  Then, since the name `x` appears later, Golang creates a copy of `i` and assigns it to `x`. Am I thinking this right?

Comment: Not quite. `pos` is bound to the closure thingy, and therefore `pos` has type `func(int) int`: it's something you call, passing one `int`, getting one `int` back. So `pos(i)` passes `i` to the closure thingy, in which you've called it `x`.  The closure thingy is the function created, then returned, inside `adder`. What we did was create a whole new function from scratch at runtime—although in fact, the actual implementation is done by cheating, in non-JIT compilers.

Answer (score 0):

The `sum` variable is inside each of the two closures when you assign `pos` and `neg`. The `sum` in the `pos` closure is updated by adding 1, 2, 3, 4 (fibonacci style) while the `sum` in the `neg` closure is updated by subtracting 2*1, 2*2, 2*3, 2*4 in each of the loop iterations.

Or, in more detail:
`pos := adder()` assigns to `pos` a function having a closure on `sum` where `sum` is 0 to begin. Then whenever you call the function `pos`, it will updated `sum` accordingly. The exact same is true with `neg`, and any other similar assignment.

Here's some similar (simpler) code in JavaScript to run in your browser console:

```
function adder() {
  var sum = 0;
  return function(i) {
    sum += i;
    return sum;
  }
}

var pos = adder();
console.log( pos(1) ); // add 1 to 0 (1)
console.log( pos(2) ); // add 2 to 1 (3)
console.log( pos(3) ); // add 3 to 3 (6)
console.log( pos(4) ); // add 4 to 6 (10)
```

Here's some background about Closures in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Hope this helps.

Comment: The question is not about JavaScript so the code and reference may be more confusing than informative to a Go developer with this question.